# Exclude sortable items dynamically on "start"

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'd like to be able to "freeze" certain items in a sortable list based on the specific item being dragged. So basically this:

```
<ul class="sortable">
   <li class="special">Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li class="lock-me">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

js

```
$( ".sortable" ).sortable({
    start : function(e, ui){
        if(ui.item.hasClass('special')){
            $( ".sortable" ).sortable('option', 'items', ':not(.lock-me)');
        }
    },
    stop : function(e, ui){
        $( ".sortable" ).sortable('option', 'items', 'li');
    }
});
```

Is this possible? Or perhaps there's another way to go about this?

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/owise1/TsSfS/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>You're not using the `items` option properly:</strike>

http://jsfiddle.net/4uxXY/

```
$(function() {
    $( ".sortable" ).sortable({
        items: ':not(.lock-me)'
    });
 });
```

Read your comment. I misunderstood.

Adding `$( ".sortable" ).sortable( "refresh" );` fixes it for me.

Here's two options:

http://jsfiddle.net/epLYY/

```
$(function () {
    $(".sortable").sortable({
        items: ':not(.lock-now)',
        start: function (e, ui) {
            console.log('started');
            if (ui.item.hasClass('special')) {
                console.log('item was .special');
                $('.sortable .lock-me').addClass('lock-now');
                $( ".sortable" ).sortable( "refresh" );
            }
        },
        stop: function (e, ui) {
            console.log('stopping');
            $('.sortable .lock-me').removeClass('lock-now');
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4G67x/

```
$(function() {
    $( ".sortable" ).sortable({
        start : function(e, ui){
            if(ui.item.hasClass('special')){
                $( ".sortable" ).sortable('option', 'items', ':not(.lock-me)').sortable( "refresh" );
            }
        },
        stop : function(e, ui){
            $( ".sortable" ).sortable('option', 'items', 'li');
        }
    });
 });
```

Comment: Your code makes the .lock-me item unsortable all the time.  What I'm looking for is a way to make the .lock-me item unsortable *only* when the .special item is being dragged.  i.e. all the rest of the time the .lock-me item is still sortable